# Receiving empty response on a PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have this API action:

```
    [HttpPost("MergeProjects")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<(bool Result, string Message)>> MergeProjects(IEnumerable<DesignProjectViewModel> projects)
    {
        var mergeResult = await _projectService.MergeProjects(projects);

        return Ok(mergeResult);
    }
```

Here is the code in action returning a message with Ok:

[image: 01]

On client side, I have this code:

```
    public async Task<(bool Result, string Message)> MergeProjects(IEnumerable<DesignProjectViewModel> selectedProjects)
    {
        var response = await ConnectingClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/designProject/mergeProjects", selectedProjects);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return (false, "Failed");

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result1 = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<(bool, string)>();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(bool Result, string Message)>(result);
    }
```

I'm experimenting.

I'm not able to find anything in the `response.Contents` to parse:

[image: 02]

What could be the issue. The API returns a json response.

Comment: Also tried `var dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);`. No dice. Empty children.

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Comment: @YiyiYou yes. I'm still fixing my API. Will update shortly

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the data into an object,and return an object：

Api:

```
[HttpPost("MergeProjects")]
    public async TestObject MergeProjects(IEnumerable<DesignProjectViewModel> projects)
    {
        var mergeResult = await _projectService.MergeProjects(projects);

        return new TestObject {  MyProperty1= mergeResult .Item1, MyProperty2=mergeResult .Item2};
    }
```

Model:

```
public class TestObject
    {
        public bool MyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<TestObject> MergeProjects(IEnumerable<DesignProjectViewModel> selectedProjects)
    {
        var response = await ConnectingClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/designProject/mergeProjects", selectedProjects);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return new TestObject { MyProperty1=false,MyProperty2="Failed"};

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(result);
    }
```